# Recover data from RAID 1 member

Tags: mount, raid, mdadm, dd

I am trying to recover data from a drive that was part of a RAID1. First a little background.

The RAID1 consisted of 2 disks (`/dev/sde` and `/dev/sdf`). It was built ~6 years ago using mdadm. In recent months, mdadm and mdstat started reporting that the RAID was degraded:

---

```
$ sudo /sbin/mdadm --detail /dev/md0

/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Tue Nov 29 11:41:44 2016
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 2930135488 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 2930135488 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 1
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Sun Jul 3 07:39:36 2022
             State : clean, degraded
    Active Devices : 1
   Working Devices : 1
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : k2:0  (local to host k2)
              UUID : 4b8ef2c5:0f0e077b:a188f0e1:4c98a3dc
            Events : 85310

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       80        0      active sync   /dev/sdf
       -       0        0        1      removed
```

---

```
$ sudo cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md0 : active raid1 sdf[0]
      2930135488 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]
      bitmap: 19/22 pages [76KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

---

To fix the RAID I simply had to re-add the missing drive:

```
$ sudo mdadm /dev/md0 --re-add /dev/sde
```

---

I've run this command a number of times over the last few months without any issues.
mdadm would be happy for a few weeks and then it would report a degraded status and I re-add the disk.

Unfortunately, the other day, when I tried to re-add the disk I got a ton of errors and the RAID would not start.

So at the moment, I have 2 disks that are not part of any RAID:

- Disk 1 which is the "healthier" disk (the one that wasn't getting dropped from the RAID) has the most current data.
- Disk 2 is the one that was getting dropped from the RAID, possibly unhealthy, and is a few weeks stale since the RAID has been degraded for a few weeks now.

I created a brand new RAID1 with brand new disks on a new box. I would like to transfer data from the healthier, more current disk (Disk 1), onto the new RAID. I plugged Disk 1 into the new box but for the life of me, I cannot seem to be able to mount the disk.

Disk 1 is currently `/dev/sdb` on the new box. Here's what `fdisk` and `gdisk` are reporting.

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 2.73 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Disk model: ST3000DM001-1ER1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 98416A55-4676-458F-8130-2E221561239D

Device      Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1      34       2081       2048    1M Microsoft LDM metadata
/dev/sdb2    2082     262177     260096  127M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb3  262178 5860533134 5860270957  2.7T Microsoft LDM data

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

---

```
$ sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdb

GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sdb: 5860533168 sectors, 2.7 TiB
Model: ST3000DM001-1ER1
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 98416A55-4676-458F-8130-2E221561239D
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 5860533134
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 0 sectors (0 bytes)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              34            2081   1024.0 KiB  4201  LDM metadata partition
   2            2082          262177   127.0 MiB   0C01  Microsoft reserved ...
   3          262178      5860533134   2.7 TiB     4200  LDM data partition
```

The "LDM data partition" labels are weird. It's been so long I don't remember where I got the disk from but this is definitely the healthier disk that was part of the RAID1.

Anyway, I tried to mount the drive with the obvious:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt/hdd
mount: /mnt/hdd: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

$ sudo mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt/hdd
mount: /mnt/hdd: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb3, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Next, I probed the disk to see what sort of file system is on there:

```
$ sudo fsck -N /dev/sdb
[/usr/sbin/fsck.ext2 (1) -- /dev/sdb] fsck.ext2 /dev/sdb
```

I tried various combinations of the mount command using the -t option (e.g. -t ext2 and -t ext4) and sdb[1-3] with no luck.

I also tried to create a new RAID using the disk without any luck.

```
$ sudo mdadm --assemble --readonly /dev/md1 /dev/sdb
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdb
mdadm: /dev/sdb has no superblock - assembly aborted
```

No superblock is concerning. I can only imagine that if got blown away when I tried to re-add the missing drive the other day (see above).

Since the disk labels mention LDM I figured I would try ldmtool:

```
$ sudo ldmtool create all
[]
```

I'm sorta stumped at the moment. One thought is to use dd to clone the disk onto my new RAID. Since the RAID is an ext4 file system perhaps dd will copy data that I can use? Something like this maybe?

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/sdb3 of=/dev/md0 bs=100M conv=sync,noerror status=progress
```

Any other thoughts/suggestions for how to transfer the data from Disk 1 onto the new RAID?

Comment: You might want to look into using [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) to recover the files and copy them to the new location using the P command after it lists the partitions that will allow you to copy files from the old partition to a new location.  You install it in Ubuntu by typing in `sudo apt install testdisk`.

Comment: @Terrance, that app is super cool. I'm able to dive into the disk and copy directories onto the new RAID. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using @Terrance suggestion, I installed TestDisk. It was able to access the old RAID partition and recover files. I have posted a few screenshots for reference.

Select Disk:

[image: Select Disk]

Select Partition:

[image: Select Partition]

Once the partition is selected, I was able to list files and copy files to a new disk. Copying a directory produced some unexpected results so I had to select individual files instead. All in all, it worked great and I was able to recover all my files from my old RAID 1 disk.